# How to get sorted dictionary from another one instead of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have `Dict ={'Deblai': [100, 1], 'Blocage': [10, 4], 'Beton de propreté': [50, 2]}` dictionary and want to sort it based on the second element of the value which is a list.

I tried `OrderedDict = sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])` but it returns an ordered list instead of a dictionary.

This is what I expect :

```
OrderedDict = {('Deblai', [100, 1]), ('Beton de propreté', [50, 2]), ('Blocage', [10, 4])}
```

How I can get a dictionary instead of list ?

Comment: What you say you expect is a set, not a dict.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @KellyBundy I needed to sort it based on the second value of each list in the values of the dictionary, while the OP in this question has a dictionary with values without lists. I found some answers but they only work on earlier version of python.

Comment: That's just a slightly different comparison criterion for the dict values. And what you were missing was turning the sorted items back into a dict, which the answers there show how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using dictionary comprehension like this:

```
unsorted_dct ={'Deblai': [100, 1], 'Blocage': [10, 4], 'Beton de propreté': [50, 2]}
sorted_dct = {k: v for k, v in sorted(unsorted_dct.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])}
print(sorted_dct)
```

output:

```
{'Deblai': [100, 1], 'Beton de propreté': [50, 2], 'Blocage': [10, 4]}
```

Comment: It worked for me this way as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since normal dictionaries preserve the ordering in which their keys were inserted, you're most of the way there; just take the list of items and pass it to the `dict` constructor.  Making it an actual `OrderedDict` ([yes, that's an actual thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)) isn't necessary.

```
>>> my_dict = {'Deblai': [100, 1], 'Blocage': [10, 4], 'Beton de propreté': [50, 2]}
>>> sorted_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
>>> sorted_dict
{'Deblai': [100, 1], 'Beton de propreté': [50, 2], 'Blocage': [10, 4]}
```

You probably don't want to name your instances `Dict` and `OrderedDict`, since these are the names of standard classes (and you should name instances with `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` regardless).

Comment: It worked!! I really appreciate your help. Thank you